# Merging in github

Tags: github

I'm working on a collaborative HTML website with a friend.  He has made a suggestion to modify two of the links on my page.  I only want to use one of his two suggestion.  How do I, on Github, only choose part of what he wants to change, to be merged into the rest?

Comment: How did he make this suggestion?  Pull request?  Commit to `master`?

Comment: he did it though a pull request

Comment: I would add a comment on the PR, explaining that you would like to only change one of the links, and asking to modify its PR (by emending it or by adding a commit). Once ready, you'd merge it as is.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to handle this situation. All commits are on a given collection of files (blob), so this could work out in a few different ways:

1. The pull request includes two separate commits, one of which you do not wish to include. You (a) merge the pull request (b) back out of the commit you don't wish to include using something like `git rebase -i HEAD~3` to include the last three commits (your merge and the two edits by your friend). [This blog post](http://wahlnetwork.com/2015/07/02/interactive-rebase/) is helpful to understand interactive rebasing
2. The pull request includes a single commit of both of these lines. You can choose to:

   - Merge the commits noting that you will manually edit the file after in a subsequent commit
   - Ask your friend to add another commit that includes the removal of that line (you can do that on the PR branch and wait for that update before merger -- Pull Requests are updated as the fork is updated)

All three of these cases end up in the same conclusion, but they have different workflows that may be preferred to trigger certain builds (in Travis CI, for example) or to document certain actions in your commit history. No matter what, don't over think it and pick whatever works for you and your collaborators.